# SQLBulkCopy and Dates (1/1/1753)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ado.net, sqlbulkcopy

I've got an application which has been working fine for quite a while, but there is an annoying item that continues to get in the way on occasion.

Let's say that I use an object such as OracleDataReader or MySQLDataReader to pass the data to the sqlbulkcopy object for insert.  Let's assume that all the columns maps just fine and for the most part, it all works well.

Granted, I don't have control over the source application or database (which is either MySQL or Oracle).  So some goof goes into a different application and puts in a date on the invoice table of 5/31/0210.  He really meant to put in 5/31/2010, but the application he's using is not validating the data very tightly and the Oracle database accepts it.  For all intensive purposes, the data of 5/31/0210 is a valid date for the Oracle db.  It might be stupid in terms of data entry, but it is what it is at this point.

Now our OracleDataReader comes along and is transferring this invoice table over to SQL Server via the SQLBulkCopy.  It is passing the data to perfectly matched table with the right column names and data types.  You can see what is going to happen.  This date of 05/31/0210 from Oracle is not accepted by the SQL Server db engine, as the DATETIME field only allows dates from 1/1/1753 to 12/31/9999.

When it encounters this record, it simply fails and gives an overflow error.  It doesn't skip the record, it kills the feed.  So if it happens a thousand records in on a million record table, you don't get the remaining 999,000 records.

Is there anyway to get around this issue so that the feed will continue?

Ideally, I'd like to move the receiving SQL Server DB to 2008 and use DATETIME2, which would allow for these goofy dates, but unfortunately not all my clients are ready to move to this version yet, so I'm stuck with DATETIME in SQL 2000/2005/2008.

Any ideas on how to get around this without changing the SQL?  Ideally, I wouldn't mind if it just skipped the record.  I know that I could do this in the SQL for the datareder, but this would be extremely complicated when you have twenty date fields in a single query.  It would be maintenance nightmare.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to change the datetime column type to varchar. Then add a derived column for converting the string to datetime. The trick would be to use a function in the derived column to validate the date and put an arbitrary datetime if the coversion will fail. If you do heavy date comparisons, persist the computed column and/or index it.

I say all of this under the impression that sqlbulkcopy is not able to do transforms. Maybe you can. Hopefully, someone will chime in with a way to.

SSIS would be great in this situation, as you could do the transform and also get the performance benefits of the bulk update lock.